# How can I add a MBtiles file to MapCache

Tags: mbtiles, mapcache

I have a large WebP compressed MBtiles file, which I would like to serve directly via MapCache.

At the moment my MapCache configuration is caching many layers on disc which are served by my MapServer as a WMTS.

```
<cache name="disk" type="disk">
  <base>/mnt/cache</base>
  <symlink_blank />
  <creation_retry>3</creation_retry>
</cache>
```

Is it possible to skip MapServer and directly add a MBtiles file to my MapCache configuration so I can make use of the small filesize provided by the WebP compression?

Or is it at least possible to serve a MBtiles file via MapServer?

Any suggestions or workarounds are welcome.